# SharePoint List (Discussion Board)

Tags: list, custom-list

Does anyone know if it is possible to expand list items to look something like the link below? It seems doubtful as there is no evidence of columns at all. Just thought i'd ask.

http://www.corasworks.net/images/idea_community_screenshot_large.gif

Answer (score 0):

I think so. But it require a lot of customization work on the layout including the list page, the input form and reply form. I would use Jquery + CSS.